# React-redux and React Native error handling for expired JWT

Tags: react-native, redux, jwt, express-jwt

I have a system where the authentication is based around JWT. I have a JWT auth token, and a refresh token on the client. The refresh token is stored in the database on the server, and is used to refresh the JWT once the JWT expires every 12 hours - pretty standard setup I believe.

My issue is incorporating it in to my React Native project and handling token expiration. The user will likely be performing many API calls to their "protected" areas which require the JWT, but once the JWT expires it will send back a "UnauthorizedError" like so:

```
router.use('/protected', ejwt({secret: config.secret}));
//catch any errors if the JWT is not valid
router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    res.status(401).send({
      success: false,
      error: "UnauthorizedError"
    });
  }
});
```

This will send back to the RN app that the JWT has expired, but at this point I would like the app to send another request back to the server generate a new JWT, but I'm not sure of a way to do this most efficiently for every API call initiated from my app. Each API call *could* call a function to check the server if the returned value is "UnauthorizedError", but I know this isn't the best way:

```
return AuthApi.someApiCall(token).then(response => {
    if(response.success){
        //do some success stuff
    }else{
        //this seems bad to be repeated for every API call
        checkToken(response).then(() => {
            dispatch(updateAuthToken());
        });
    }
})
```

I've been looking around and Redux middleware looks promising, but I don't know if there's a more established way perhaps, or anyone has any other thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be interested to hear what you find. We're using a system like the one you mention. Basically, each response is parsed, if it's Unauthorized, we call for a new token.  The function for the new token accepts the url, body, and method as parameters so that when it gets the new token it can just re-issue the get/post/whatever and return those results.  It ends up being semi-recursive.  Our biggest issue was watching for changed passwords since that throws an Unauthorized error also but won't allow a new token to be generated